# Does it make sense to mark a question as opinion-based when there are no answers to it?

Tags: discussion

Say, I ask a question, and it quickly gets marked as opinion-based, even having no answers at all.

I mean, I would be happy to have at least one answer, be it or be it not someone else's subjective opinion (if only there were non-subjective opinions).

I suppose marking it with that label means that people for the sake of good hope to save the community from the thread going wild when commenters begin arguing in the comments and answers?

But, you can't say if it's going to be like that until you see those personal opinions in comments or answers?

Shouldn't be this marking available after having at least one answer, which is a subjective personal opinion which doesn't apply to all possible cases?

Comment: Questions that should be closed, should be closed immediately. If we wait around until they're answered, then people will have incentive to continue asking off-topic questions.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make sense to mark a question as opinion-based when there are
>   no answers to it?

Yes

---

[Opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) means:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or
>   specific expertise.

Comments or at-least one answer is not always need to make a decision whether a question is opinion based. One can use his experience and gut-feel to decide.

For example: **Which programming language is best?** can be safely marked as "Primarily opinion based" without waiting for comments or a couple of answers.

Comment: If people read the question and answers, they can define themselves if the question is opinion-based or not, can't they? Even being a so-called 'opinion-based', even a single answer can give a clue to a solution for those who in need of it. Why should we think people can't differentiate between opinion-based, or purely factual ones? Regardless someone's opinion on being a question opinion-based, answers can be useful.

Comment: Closing a question is a way to demote others from asking similar question and invite OP or other readers to edit the question and make it specific or comment to make the question clearer. Opinion based questions are better suited for chat in my opinion.

Comment: Marking questions as opinion-based is opinion-based in itself, and this decision is set on one's experience, facts she knows, and so on, as all the opinions we see. So, when you mark some question as opinion-based, you say "In my opinion, this question leads to people sharing their opinions. I can't prove why it's so, as this decision is a result of combining a set of facts and my experience."

Comment: Exactly you are very right. That's why you need multiple votes before a question can be closed as opinion-based (unless you have net 1000+ up-votes in the area of question). And if people think it was wrong to close the question, they can mark the question to re-open. So in short whether a question is opinion-based or not is a collective decision of multiple experienced users. Isn't it?